# Ruby programming error (undefined local variable)

Tags: ruby, variables, syntax-error, undefined, nameerror

I tried to make a credit card payment calculator. Here's the whole code:

```
m_counter = 0

def calc_payment
  payment_percentage = payment / balance * 100
  monthly_apr = apr / 12
  while balance > 0
   m_counter = m_counter + 1
   balance = balance / 100 * monthly_apr
   balance = balance - payment
  end
  puts
  puts "Monthly payment: $" + payment
  puts "Balance payoff: " + m_counter + " months" 
end

puts "Welcome to your credit card payment calculator!"
puts

puts "Please tell me your credit card balance."
balance = gets.chomp.to_f

puts "Please enter your interest rate %."
apr = gets.chomp.to_f

puts "How much $ would you like to pay every month?"
payment = gets.chomp.to_f

calc_payment
```

I'm getting an error message:

> 'calc_payment': undefined local variable or method 'payment' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: Vori, a small suggestion: `(payment / balance) * 100` or (better) `100 * payment / balance` rather than `payment / balance * 100` (clearer).  Also, you could have `puts "hi\n\n"` rather than `puts "hi"; puts; puts` (stylistic difference only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue revolves around variable scope. `payment` has a local scope, and therefore the function `calc_payment` cannot "see" it. Here I modified your program so that you pass `payment`, `balance`, and `apr` into the `calc_payment` function. I also moved `m_counter` into the function as well.

```
def calc_payment(payment, balance, apr)
  m_counter = 0
  payment_percentage = payment / balance * 100
  monthly_apr = apr / 12

  while balance > 0
   m_counter = m_counter + 1
   balance = balance / 100 * monthly_apr
   balance = balance - payment
  end

  puts
  puts "Monthly payment: $" + payment
  puts "Balance payoff: " + m_counter + " months" 

end

puts "Welcome to your credit card payment calculator!"
puts

puts "Please tell me your credit card balance."
balance = gets.chomp.to_f

puts "Please enter your interest rate %."
apr = gets.chomp.to_f

puts "How much $ would you like to pay every month?"
payment = gets.chomp.to_f

calc_payment(payment, balance, apr)
```